# Changing the format of array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, format

Is there a method you can use to change the format of an array (as in the way it is separated by commas and enclosed in brackets when it's printed out). I want to get rid of the brackets and commas so that the terms are only separated by spaces.

Answer (score 6):

Then don't use the Arrays.toString() method, write your own:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (xxxx val : array) {
    sb.append(val).append(" ");
}
sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use Guava's [Joiner](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) class for full control of your output.

E.g.,

```
Integer[] foo = new Integer[] {1, 2, 3};
System.out.println(Joiner.on(' ').join(foo);
```

gives `1 2 3`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `,` and the `(` and `)`

```
String formatedString = myArrayList.toString()
                                  .replace(",", " ")  //remove the commas
                                  .replace("[", "")   //remove the right bracket
                                  .replace("]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.
E.g.:

```
   String[] array = {"A","B"};
   System.out.println(         StringUtils.join(array, "_")           );
```